# Water-repellent windshield coating and automatic car wash: Do they mix?

Tags: carwash

I want to apply <del>Rain-X</del> a water repellent to my windshield.  To make sure the glass is clean first I'm going to run the car through an automatic car wash.

1. I assume I want the cheapest external wash with *no* added *Clear Coat Protectant* or *Tri-Polish Wax* or other superior Premium add-ons which would coat the windshield before I added the water repellent: True or False?
2. I assume that *after* I've rubbed on the water repellent (and let it dry) I can then run it through the car wash *with* their high quality sprayed on wax and/or coatings and that won't impact the repellency of my water repellent coating: True or False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use these water repellent products frequently. Typically I hand wash my vehicles, however I have used automatic car washes too. In my experience, it doesn't really matter what the car is washed with (including the windscreen) as long as the repellent product is applied properly according to the instructions afterwards.

Subsequent washing reduces the effect of the repellent product, so I certainly **WOULD NOT** apply it before washing, always after.

For more info, Rain-X have a good hints and tips page:
https://www.rainx.co.uk/tips-and-info/

Comment: Note that if you apply it *after* washing, you should skip the wax cycle. I always clean the glass with rubbing alcohol before applying to remove any residual contaminants.